# How to convert datatable column values to an array by columnindex?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I am currently working on a grading system where I have to place multiple int values into an array. These values are stored in an AccessDB under 18 columns. I am currently working on a method that grabs the column values from the DB and places them all in an Array. I found multiple solutions online, but they all require the column name as a string.

Furthermore, I want to create a method that can take an index number for the columns instead of a string name. Here is a quick explanation of the method that I am creating:

1. Grab values from grading subtest;
2. Place values in array;
3. Grade test;
4. Clear array;
5. Grab next subtest;
6. Repeat process until all 18 subtests are done.

Here is the code for the method i currently have:

```
using (var exportAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ZoekQuery, connection))
                        {
                            exportAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
                            exportAdapter.Fill(NormDB);
                            Normen = NormDB.AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.Field<int>(1)).ToArray();
                            //testbox.Text = Normen.ToString();
                        }
```

As you can see, I place the DB values in a data table and then try to do place the values in an array. This current code crashes because d.field() only takes a string name as parameter and I want it to accept an index number.

If the question is unclear, I can provide more info.

thanks.

Comment: Tables aren't arrays. A table defines a *relation* between the values in its fields. That's where the Relational in RDBMS comes from, why tables don't have arbitrary numbers of columns, why mixing types in the same column is a bug. If you want to to access rows and fields by number you can load the data into any container that allows this, eg a DataTable. In a DataRow you can access columns by index as well as by name. The same with a DbDataReader. If you want to load the data into a 2D int array, you'll have to write the code to do this

Comment: Thanks, but I already placed the data in a datatable, is this code ```NormDB.AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.Field<int>(1)).ToArray();``` not valid for an datatable then?

Comment: `I place the DB values in a data table` you don't need a DbDataAdapter for this. Once you have a `DbDataReader` you can use `DataTable.Load` to load the table. You aren't using the DataTable directly though, you're using LINQ to DataSet. If you use the DataTable's rows, you can use [DataRow's indexer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0) to retrieve values by index, eg `object o=row[0];`. You can retrieve all of a row's values with a single call with [ItemArray](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Yes i got it, i was confused and realized i didn't even need that linq code. I was trying to retrieve .columns but ofcourse i have to retreieve .rows.... thanks!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos datatable.Load uses an adapter internally, and I'd advocate that an adapter is generally easier to use; one does not need (and indeed the OP does not have) a DbDataReader. (In summary, if someone came to me with a DataaAdapter way that was working to load a table, I wouldn't see any merit in directing them towards using datatable.Load instead)